# Returning member class in C++

Tags: c++, types

In the following example:

```
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
        ...
    }
    B Method(B argument);
}

A::B A::Method(B argument);
```

Why exactly is the scope required for return type, while not for argument type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [basic.lookup.qual]/3,

> In a declaration in which the *declarator-id* is a *qualified-id*, names used before the *qualified-id* being declared
>   are looked up in the defining namespace scope; names following the *qualified-id* are looked up in the scope
>   of the member’s class or namespace.

The return type comes before the *qualified-id* being declared (that is, `A::Method`) whereas the parameter type comes after it, so the parameter type's name is automatically looked up in the scope of `A`, while the return type's name is not. We can avoid the extra qualification using a trailing return type.

```
auto A::Method(B argument) -> B;
```

Comment: Am I the only guy who's had to read the standard quote 10 times slowly in order to get it ?

Comment: @user I realize it's not so easy to read if you're not familiar with the vocabulary. That's why I also explained below.